# Comparing DataTables headers for filtering in Vuetify?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I have a data table and its headers values are months. Now I want to select from the array of objects the matching months and value associated with it and show it in this table in an associated column.

Here is the Headers:-

```
headers:[
  {
    text:'1',
    align:'left',
    value:'month'
 },
 {
    text:'2',
    align:'left',
    value:'month'
 },
 {
    text:'3',
    align:'left',
    value:'month'
 },
 {
    text:'4',
    align:'left',
    value:'month'
 }
]
```

An array of objects looks like this:-

```
array:[
  {
    month:1,
    value: 200
  },
 {
    month:2,
    value: 300
  },
 {
   month:3,
   value: 400
  },
 {
   month:4,
   value: 500
  }
]
```

now in the datatable, it should be like this:-

```
+-----------------------+
|  1  |  2  |  3  |  4  |   <- headers.text
+-----------------------+
| 200 | 300 | 400 | 500 |   <- array.value
+-----------------------+
```

I have tried simple data table like this:-

```
<v-data-table
  v-bind:headers="headers"
  :items="array"
  hide-actions              
  class="elevation-1"
    >             
    <template slot="headers" slot-scope="props">
        <tr>                    
            <th v-for="header in props.headers" :key="header.text"
                                  v-bind:align="header.align"
                                  class="text-xs-left"
                                >   
                 <div class="text-xs-left">{{$t(header.text)}}</div> 
            </th>
        </tr>                 
    </template>
    <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">  
        <tr>
            <td>props.item.value</td>               
        </tr>                
    </template>           
</v-data-table>
```

but how do I know which values are belong to which months? suppose in an array there are more than 4 months and the early months are missing then I am not sure how to apply this?
Does someone have some idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this; not best solution but that is work;

```
<body>
<div id="app-2">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td v-for="head in headers">{{head.text}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td v-for="head in headers">{{head.value}}</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</div>

 <script>
   var app2 = new Vue({
    el: '#app-2',
    data: {
        headers: [
          {
           text: '1',
           align: 'left',
           value: 'month'
          },
          {
           text: '2',
           align: 'left',
           value: 'month'
          },
          {
           text: '3',
           align: 'left',
           value: 'month'
           },
           {
            text: '4',
            align: 'left',
            value: 'month'
           }
        ]
    }
})
var array = [
 {
     month: 1,
     value: 200
 },
{
    month: 2,
    value: 300
},
{
    month: 3,
    value: 400
},
{
    month: 4,
    value: 500
}
];

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    for (var k = 0; k < array.length; k++) {
        if (array[i].month == app2.$data.headers[k].text) {
            (app2.$data.headers[k].value = array[i].value)
        }
    }

}
```